# Soft Keyboard pushed button up above it. How to fix it?

Tags: android, keyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I have ConstraintLayout with ScorllView and Button below it (attached to bottom of the screen. When I am editing EditText input inside ScrollView. Then appearing keyboard is moving my ScrollView content up (desired behaviour, so I can scroll to the end of it) but it also pushing button up (undesired behaviour).

I think I can change windowAdjustMode, maybe I could detect keyboard showing and then hide this button? But this two solutions aren't perfect. [image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <EditText /> goes here 
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/wizard_singup_step_submit_button"
        style="@style/FormSubmitButton"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Just use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`** inside your `activity` tag in manifest file it will work

Comment: But if I change this it will be possible to scroll to the end of ScrollView? Of course I will try it in the minute.

Comment: Share your xml layout with question

Comment: I have added xml sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, haven't tried it myself, try adding the below code to your `activity` tag inside your manifest

Edit - added `stateHidden` to achieve what you're looking for, the button will be at the bottom and the elements inside the scroll view can be scrolled.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element) - 
`adjustPan` - The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Edit 2 - Code for calculating the height of the Keyboard

```
myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parent.getRootView().getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
                    Log.d("Keyboard Size", "Size: " + heightDifference);

                }
            });
```

Add that `heightDifference` by creating a View Programmatically and setting it's height.

Edit 3 -

Use this to hide the keyboard

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I've edited the answer to achieve what you're looking for, hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I will try it in 1 hour.

Comment: Sure, hope this helps!

Comment: It works but it scroll view content is behind the keyboard like bottom of scroll view attached to bottom of screen. If there is more content it can be scrolled but this last part equal keyboard height is hidden. But I think there want be better solution. I consider about hiding just Submit Button on Keyboard Show but Android doesn't have native keyboard show/hide listeners just some workarounds

Comment: Not the most optimum way to go about it but, what you can do is calculate the height of the keyboard (have added the code in the answer) and use that height at the bottom of the view so that it scrolls till the bottom view even after the keyboard is open.

Comment: Or you can hide the keyboard when scrolling the list, you can add an `OnScrollListener` and hide the keyboard programmaticaly (added the code in the answer) like you mentioned.

Comment: Yes I have used this listener and I am hiding button. It seems to work ok.